# Profiling database queries and latency of ordinary functions in django

Tags: python, django, profiling, django-debug-toolbar, django-silk

We need some tool for analyzing non view functions of our django project particularly the celery-beat tasks.
So, is there any tool for profiling queries and latency of running ordinary functions (not views) in a django app? Preferably, is there any decorators (or any other mechanism) that can add results of profiling an ordinary function to the output of tools like django-silk or django-debug-toolbar?

Comment: https://flower.readthedocs.io/en/latest/  is used to monitor celery tasks. Not sure if you will get time taken by any task to get executed. Please investigate on that. In production you generally use process manager like supervisor which produces logs. In those logs you can easily check what is the time taken by task. That's how i check. Please post answer if you can get to know about any real time monitoring tool which can be accessed over web.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last, I used the silk middleware code and made a decorator for profiling random functions like requests then used it for profiling my tasks. This was somehow patchy but worked. The code is accessible [here](https://gist.github.com/mh-keshavarz/eb966905428ef9017ee1ff7d25518bba).